# Unable to Start Docker Desktop on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-desktop

I was getting bellow error while trying to start Docker Desktop on Windows 10.

`Unable to stop - The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Service 'Hyper-V Host Compute Service (vmcompute)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service vmcompute on computer '.'.`

Comment: So you use Windows Home or Pro? As far as know docker needs the Windows Pro version and does Not work with home. You can check via cmd and using the command systeminfo If hyper-V is usable

Comment: I am on Windows 10 Pro

Comment: I found some information in this Site https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements?redirectedfrom=MSDN unfortunately it is written in German, maybe it is switchable in english

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps **(1-8)** mentioned in the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126279/cant-start-docker-on-windows).

Hope this helps! 
-Kunal

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue .

"Hyper-V Host Compute Service" does not start after updating Windows 10 with latest security patches and this caused docker start failures after reboot.

Try out the steps mentioned below-

-

> Open "Window Security"
>
> - "App & Browser control"
> - Click "Exploit protection settings" at the bottom
> - Switch to "Program settings" tab
> - Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
> - Click "Edit"
> - Scroll down to "Code flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck "Override system settings"
> - Start vmcompute from powershell "net start vmcompute"

Answer (score -2):

On the docker icon, right click and click trobleshoot. Click on "Reset to factory defaults",
[image]